# WPF Load images from selected Folders in Tab control

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, opendialog

I Want the UserControl in which Multiple Folders can be Selected where each selected Folders contains Images,Further these selected folders must be opened as a tabItem.
Say for example i have Selected "7" Folders,so that "7"Tabitems will be created,each tabitem contain images of the folder, that is **1st tab item** contain **1st Folder images**. Here the Challange is, how to get opendialog box to select multiple folders.

Comment: & what have you tried so far ... code wise?

Comment: I just created two seperated usercontrols ,one for creating dynamic tabitems and another for loading images with collectionViewsource for grouping and sorting purpose, i need to integrate this with dynamic tab usercontrol,so that every tabitem will contain this usercontrol for loading with grouping and sorting purpose. But still im confusion with the way of approching to the requirement,i mean can i use MVVM pattern or not? and i don know how to do with selecting multiple folders using OpenFiledialog or FolderBrowserDialog, so seeking some guidence for all of my questions.